# Oracle Query - Replace not working

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query where data is coming from front end into IN condition. Now the value is  coming as comma separated for eg: 002,003 or 002q, 4335f, 123d, shd4 or yuw98

My query takes value as `select * from tbl1 where userid in ('002,004')` where as it should be `userid in ('002','004')`

I tried below query to replace the string but it doesnot work.

Select * from tbl1 where 
`UserId in (''''|| Replace('004,002', ',',  ''',''') || '''');`

Same value if i use in

`Select (''''|| Replace('004,002', ',',  ''',''') || '''') from dual;`

Returns
`'004','002'`

then why does the value not run in my original query ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who were looking for solution, I found one.

`WHERE INSTRC('001, 002'), userid, 1, 1) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a query like this:

```
 select * from tbl1 where userid in ('002,004')
```

And, for some reason, you *have* to represent the list of values as a string (assuming you want to search for two values in this case), then you can use `like` to find matches:

```
where ','||userid||',' like ','||'002,004'||','
```

I encourage you to try to find a way to make `in` work, by properly constructing the query.  For one thing, this would allow the query to take advantage of an index.  But, if not reasonable, then the `like` approach will work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar thing before, but soon learned that it is not possible in Oracle. So, i worked out another solution. Hope it doesn't sound too silly. Ok here it goes

- Create separate variables based on your best assumption about no.of values the user inputs.
- Write a simple block of pl/sql code to seperate the each value and store them into variables.
- Use all these variables in your IN condition.